# PHP Can't login

Tags: php

Hello everyone I'm Junel, first year college and taking my php subject. I've created a simple Learning Management System but somehow there's a bug on my code, in "login" to be exact. so i'm humbling myself to ask your help in this particular matter. here is my code.

```
<?php
    include('dbcon.php');
    session_start();
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'")or die(mysql_error());
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);


    if ($count > 0){

    $_SESSION['id']=$row['user_id'];

    echo 'true';

    mysql_query("insert into user_log (username,login_date,user_id)values('$username',NOW(),".$row['user_id'].")")or die(mysql_error());
     }else{ 
    echo 'false';
    }   

    ?>
```

I hope you can help me. Thank You in advance and Good day everyone.

Comment: What exactly is your error? And btw `mysql` is deprecated, use `mysqli`.

Comment: what is the `bug` that you encounter?

Comment: And also you dont have to do `".$row['user_id']."`. You can try `'$row[user_id]'` instead. Not a solution but just a tip.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot login in PHP/MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20551746/cannot-login-in-php-mysql)

Comment: All users in the system cannot login including the admin. I've created another user but still it cannot login. by the way I'm really sorry if this kind of topic was already been posted. and thank you for all your responds.

Comment: Is the usernames and passwords correctly saved in the database?

Comment: Yes sir, the user I've created was successfully saved on the database. the username and password are both "admin".

Comment: what's the output ? Which errors are being shown ?
BTW : wrap the column names with ticks  ( ` )

Comment: The `mysql_*` extension has been removed, switch to PDO or MySQLi instead.

Comment: I'll echo the first comment: The `mysql` functions are deprecated (in fact, they've been removed completely from the most recent versions of PHP), so you should not be using them. If you're just learning PHP now, you need to make sure what you learn is up-to-date. It's really important. Learn how to use the PDO library for your DB access instead.

Comment: Also, the way you're adding the username and password into the query string is wide open to hackers. You need to learn how to escape your queries properly. Learning to use PDO with prepared queries will also solve this problem for you.